# How to get Pop up occupying full page using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to investigate how this effect is made in  http://work.co/grid/. Is there any plugin in jquery to implement similar effect.

Can anyone help me with this as I don't know even what the effect is called but I want to know how it is done.

Comment: improved question for better understanding.

Comment: @strickers I understand this is difficult to explain. The solution proposed by Keval could potentially work but load everything on one page. What I am trying to understand is how to you move from one page to another one using the effect of clicking one image and having it expanding onto the new page. The other only option I have in mind would be using iframes. Not sure it would actually be effective.

Comment: A similar effect it is also used here: http://doamaral.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding I think you need this type of example

http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/tgsf8n69/1/

hear I will zoom div when you click on div

```
var isFullscreen = false;
$('.zoom').click(function() {
         var d = {};
                var speed = 900;
                if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
                    d.width = "100%";
                    d.height = "100%"; 
                    isFullscreen = true;

                }
                else{ // MINIMIZATION            
                    d.width = "300px";
                    d.height = "100px";            
                    isFullscreen = false;

                }
                $(".zoom").animate(d,speed);     
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @keval this is a great starting point. However, this is slightly different then what I am after. still useful though!

Comment: If you want any help let me know